# og:url in cyrillic and Facebook OG Debugger

Tags: facebook, debugging, cyrillic

I use Joomla 3.2.4.
Until last week everything was ok with posting links in Facebook, but now when I try to post a link, FB shows only site name with a correct link to posted item, but there are no image, description etc. 
The OG Debugger says : Object at URL 'http://www.sroditeli.com/%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE.html' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

In the page code all OG tags are there - you can see the tags in the given URL. 
I have no idea what is the problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is another error (when I try your URL in debug tool), saying _“Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10003 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received”_ – I think that might rather be the _real_ cause here – your page is extremely slow (when I open it in my browser as well), and so the request timing out is probably the reason why the debug tool does not “see” any og:title, because it has actually received no data at all from your site.

Comment: It's very strange, I have never seen the error you mentioned